# undefined get set for null value even not returning in ractjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm getting undefined in updatelist for in case of emp_id is null.
Even I'm not returning anything if emp_id is null.

Please help me to fix this.

```
    const update1 = res.data.map((updatecol) => {
        if (updatecol.emp_id === null) {
        } else {
            return {
                label: updatecol.emp_name,
                value: updatecol.emp_name
            };
        }
    });

    this.setState({
        updatelist: update1
    });
```

Comment: Yes, that is Javascript. If you don't return anything, you return `undefined`.

Comment: if (updatecol.emp_id === null) { return }, still it didn't work.

Comment: Still `return` means `return undefined` both are same

Comment: What do you want to return when `updatecol.emp_id` is null?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are getting undefined. Try this way

```
const update1 = () => {

    const obj = {};

    for(let i = 0 ; i < res.data.length ; i++){

        const updatecol = res.data[i]; 

        if (updatecol.emp_id && updatecol.emp_id !== null) {
        
           obj.label = updatecol.emp_name;
           obj.value = updatecol.emp_name;  
           break;    
        } 
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Might be because updatecol.emp_id is null so I applied checked on it please check is it still error

Comment: Still I have same error. I have found in debug more that it's not reaching at updatecol.emp_id && updatecol.emp_id !== null statement.  res.data.map() contain code 200, array of data and description. In array of data, emp_id is present.

Comment: That means error is occurring some where else in code

Comment: When I pass const update1 = res.data.map((updatecol) => like this. It will read each and every array.

Comment: FYI, `map` doesn't allow `break`, It throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have you checked it has data or not in res.data?